# ADO gulp task - pass previous task's output variable as argument

Tags: azure-devops, gulp, yaml

I am trying this for quite sometime now & not able to figure out how to proceed further. My requirement is to dynamically calculate a variable in a bash task & then in next step use the same as a parameter to the gulp task. Below are my two tasks as part of the build pipeline (removed lines for simplicity)

```
          - task: Bash@3
            name: SetVariableValue
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: >
                // removed

                myvariableValue=$(do something & calculate here, assume value will be 'abc')
                
                // Set to an output variable
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;isOutput=true]$myvariableValue"

          - task: gulp@0
            displayName: Publish front-end
            inputs:
              gulpFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/../gulpfile.js
              targets: publish
              arguments: >-
                --buildId $(Build.BuildId) --buildNumber $(Build.BuildNumber) --sourceBranch $(Build.SourceBranch) --var $(myVar)
              gulpjs: >-
                $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/../node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
              enableCodeCoverage: false
```

I am using linux machines to build angular packages and the gulp publish command is used to package our code depending on the said variable.

With above steps all the rest parameters like BuildId, BuildNumber, SourceBranch are getting passed correctly but the 'var' parameter is being passed as *$(myVar)* only, rather *abc*

Can you please help me on what am I missing here? I tried multiple things like *--var $(Build.myVar)*, but not able to make it work.

Thanks

Sanjay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man all I needed was to correct the name of the step & refer it without mistyping :(

*--var $(SetVariableValue.myVar)* did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Great！ Glad to know that this issue has been resolved. You can accept this answer. This will be helpful to other users